# Why unable to initialize unity engine in Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sdk, game-engine

I am facing an error after installing exported app in android.
The error says "**unable to initialize unity engine**".
Any solution?

Comment: that's not much to go on. Are you familiar with USB debugging android apps?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the version of Unity and the Android-Support-for-Editor.

Find the local log files on your Android to help figure out what could be going wrong:

> Expected version: 2019.1.6f1. Actual version: 2019.1.0f2.

I use linux opensuse tumbleweed.